# how to create a login with java and json web service

Tags: java, php, json

I want to create a swing application and refer to  the database using json.I tried but it did not work and i'm new to json.I want to access the database using webservice.
Below my code.

Login.java

```
String username=jTextField1.getText();
    String password=jPasswordField1.getText();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("username", username);
obj.put("password", password); 



    try {
        HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost httppost= new     HttpPost("http://localhost/kolitha/json_test/index.php");
        StringEntity se=new StringEntity ("myjson: "+obj.toString());
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        System.out.print(se);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println("result is "+responseBody);


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("Cannot establish connection!");
    }
```

**index.php**
here is my php file and i want to get the json object and parse username and password to query and send the response java application.

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('php://input',0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

$username;
$password;

    foreach($json_output -> details as $detail)
{
$username = $detail -> username;
$password = $detail -> password;
    }


    $login_result = false;

    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    IF(!$connect)
    {
        die('Failed Connecting to Database: '.mysql_error());
}

$d = mysql_select_db("kolitha_json_test");
    if (!$d)
{
     echo "db not selected";
 }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

   if (!$result){
        $login_result = false;
        return $login_result;
        die("Could not run the Query ".mysql_error());
    } else {
        $login_result = true;
        return $login_result;
    }

     ?>
```

Comment: what is the error dude?

Comment: it doesn't return any true or false. i think the fault is in php code.

Comment: Did you notice that you're not returning anything from your PHP page to get read in the Java side? Please review your PHP code since this has nothing to do with the Java side. I would recommend you having a JSON response from your PHP page. Here's a solution: [How to generate json response using php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9463004/1065197)

Comment: i return true or false boolean expressions.isn't that enough?

Comment: @user2508416 looks like you know nothing about web development. A web response can't be a simple boolean nor int nor your type. Maybe you want to use a Web Service instead.

Comment: yes i'm new to web development and my json knowledge is 2 days old. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
```

And check if the response has an entity

```
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

 if (entity != null) {
   InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
   String responseBody = RestClient.convertStreamToString(instream);
    System.out.println("result is "+responseBody);
}
```