# How to create a simple json response

Tags: php, html, json

```
<?php
$num1 = $_REQUEST['num1'] ;
$num2 = $_REQUEST['num2'] ;
$tot = $num1 + $num2 ;
echo "Total is ".$tot ;
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php" >
<label>#1</label>
<input type="text" name="num1" />
<label>#2</label>
<input type="text" name="num2" />
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
</html>
```

I have this php . What I am trying to do is, as soon as I enter the submit button the result should be a json response. Or a response over url. I am new to json response.

Is this possible? Please help.

Comment: http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/php-creating-json-response-a-real-world-example/

Comment: http://www.happycode.info/php-json-response/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9463004/2439156

Answer (score 0):

```
$num1 = $_REQUEST['num1'] ;
$num2 = $_REQUEST['num2'] ;

$tot = $num1 + $num2 ;

$response["Total"] = $tot;
return json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$response['status'] = '1';
$response['message'] = 'success, you have Json encoded something';

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with the Javascript bits for completeness. This should also work cross domain, since I prepend jsoncallback in the response.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
            self = $(this);
            event.preventDefault();
            $.getJSON("/test.php", $(this).serializeArray(), function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    self.append("<h3>" + response.total + "</h3>");
                    });
            });
});
</script>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<label>#1</label>
<input type="text" name="num1" />
<label>#2</label>
<input type="text" name="num2" />
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$num1 = $_REQUEST['num1'];
$num2 = $_REQUEST['num2'];
$response["total"] = $num1 + $num2;
echo $_REQUEST['jsoncallback'] . json_encode($response);
?>
```